# How to make Beyond Compare ignore whitespace, but still show changes in comments

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

Beyond Compare has a button and menu item **Ignore Unimportant Differences**. When selected the diff will ignore whitespace and various formatting differences, but will also ignore changes in comments. How can I make it show comment changes, but still ignore whitespace?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Use the **Session** **→** **Session Settings** menu item.
2. Go to the **Importance** tab.
3. In the list box on the top left, check **Comments**.
4. In the drop-down at the bottom left, choose **Also update session defaults**. (if you want to change it permanently)
5. Click **OK**.
6. Verify that **View** **→** **Ignore Unimportant Differences** is enabled.

Comment: Do you know how to get it to ignore white space for folder compare?

Comment: "Ignore Unimportant Differences" - where is this? Can't see it in BC 3

Comment: "Ignore Unimportant Differences" is in the View menu.

Comment: i cant fine "comments". May be i have newer BeyondCompare. I found "leading white spaces in the lower menu" though

Comment: @M.UsmanKhan It will be in the grammar elements box once you choose a source type on the Format tab for the Left and Right.

Answer (score 0):

For AutoHotKey users, here is a hotkey script to do this with a single hotkey which toggles comments between unimportant and important.

```
#NoEnv  
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#SingleInstance force

;Make hotkeys specific to BeyondCompare
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe BCompare.exe

;Hotkey here, Numpad5 is being used, could be anything
Numpad5::
send, !se{right}{right}{tab}{tab}{tab}{down}{down}{down}{down}{down}{space}{enter}
return
```